# what is the meaning of the pipe symbol "|" in front of a variable

Tags: verilog

I am analysing some verilog code and found something like

```
wire z = |a & b;
```

while simultation the code behaves just like

```
wire z = a & b;
```

so i was wondering what is the meaning of the `|` (pipe) symbol? Does it have any impact on the simulation/synthesis?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a [bit-wise reduction operator](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/operators2.html). `|a & b` means you apply a logical OR to all bits of `a` (producing a single bit) and then do a logical AND of that bit and `b`. `|a` has no effect when `a` is a single bit.

Nevertheless, it's quite common to see bit-wise reduction applied to single bit values. One typical case is auto-generated code where the actual width of `a` may depend on the configuration. Another possibility is this being legacy code where `a` once had several bits. When `a` became a single bit value, this line was still technically correct so the now unneeded reduction operator was left in.